# Merge 2 lists in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, merge

```
List 1 = ['_','_','_','a','_']
List 2 = ['d','_','_','_','_']
```

I'd like to merge two lists of identical length where:

1. Alphabets in List 2 must replace special characters in List 1 but
2. Special characters in List 2 must not replace alphabets in List 1.

The merged list would look like this:

```
Merged List = ['d','_','_','a','_']
```

Any tips on the fastest way to accomplish this would be much appreciated!

Comment: What are "special characters"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enumerate` and list comprehension:

```
mergedlist = [c if c.isalnum() else list2[i] for i, c in enumerate(list1)]
```

NB/ I have used `isalnum` for making the distinction with "special" characters. Depending on your definition of what makes a character special, you may need a different function to do that.